# get a list of directory entries in a directory with broken symbolic link

Tags: common-lisp, osx-yosemite, ccl

I'm using CCL on OS X Yosemite.

When I use e.g.

```
(directory "*")
```

in directory

```
/Users/Tom
```

for listing all directory entries, but `/Users/Tom` contains a broken symbolic link (e.g. `slime` where the directory linked to does not exist any more),

```
File #P"/Users/Tom/slime" does not exist.
   [Condition of type CCL::SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR]
```

is thrown.

Is there a way to get get a list of directory entries in such a directory with a broken symbolic link?

Comment: So you want to exclude broken symlinks in the listing?

Comment: Not neccessarily. Just get a list of all directory entries. Checking what they are (files/directories/symbolic links (working/broking) is another task that doesn't seem trivial or even possible in cl.

Comment: OK, well I don't know the language, but this looks like an exception handling issue.

Comment: Sadly not: even if you catch the exception, you don't get the remaining entries.

Comment: What restarts are available?

Comment: Restarts:
      0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
      1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
      2: [ABORT-BREAK] Reset this thread
      3: [ABORT] Kill this thread

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use the non-standard CCL extension `:follow-links nil`. Most implementations have something similar as an extra option to [directory](http://l1sp.org/cl/directory).

Comment: You are right. I tried this also and it works - with some very strange behavior in the REPL if executed from there. But I thought that a CL standard way to do that should exist. The behaviour of `directory` is not specified in detail in the CLHS - but IMHO following links is not what `directory` should do by default.

Comment: `directory` is specified to return pathnames corresponding to the truenames of the files. Most implementations interpret truename as being the target of the symbolic link. The typical behavior of directory is consistent with that interpretation.

Comment: You are right with the truenames according to the CLHS. Still I think, that `directory` doesn't do the right thing because it's just unusable in the current form and that feels wrong to me. And there doesn't seem to be a way to access the real directory entries.